# How can I schedule to run a controller automatically in my MVC web app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a database that continuously tracks temperature. I also have a controller (Controller A) that calculates the average temperature within 60 minutes (this is can be changed by the user in the front-end). If Controller A's calculation exceeds the set max temperature, it calls another controller that notifies the user via email (Controller B).

```
 Pseudo code:

 while(Controller A) <-- runs in the background
 {
    if(max temperature is reached)
       Call Controller B
 }
```

My question is, how can I continuously make the server run Controller A without making things extremely slow? I read that SignalR can do automation stuff but I'm not quite sure which keywords I should be looking for.

If someone could point me at the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Will there be a user connected to your application at all times via browser?  If not, then SignalR isn't going to help.  It sounds to me like you need a Windows Service or something running in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, and yes users will be logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be running such a long running process on an ASP.NET thread. You have 2 options

**1)** Create a windows service which keeps checking your db table in every **n** minutes and do the things needed( like sending the email etc..)

**2)** Messaging services like ServiceBus /RabbitMQ

**3)** If the input is going to the db table via controller in your application, you can pass this value to another service/thread/process to do the calculation and sending the emails.

---

Copied from [Mason's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139830/mason) comment in the answer for future readers : There are other options, like Hangfire, FluentScheduler, Quartz etc. These libraries have been designed around some of the pitfalls of manually running some code in the background in ASP.NET. Scott Hanselman  describes them in an [excellent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) with sample code.

Comment: There are other options, like Hangfire, FluentScheduler, Quartz etc. These libraries have been designed around some of the pitfalls of manually running some code in the background in ASP.NET. Scott Hanselman (MS employee) describes them [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: Yes. Those are sound solutions.

Comment: Thanks Shyju and mason for the link and info. I'll try to implement those solutions.

Comment: Thanks @mason I moved your comment to the answer for future readers. Hope that is fine. Let me know otherwise :)

Comment: My intention with my comment was for you to incorporate it into your answer if you saw fit.